# Distinct() not working as expected, and not calling Equals method, on a List of user defined objects

Tags: c#, linq, overriding

I have created my own definition of Tuple so that I can have my own definition of the Equals method, in which (1, 3) is equal to (3, 1). The Code is below.

```
public struct Tuple : IEquatable<object>
{
    public int Item1 { get; set; }
    public int Item2 { get; set; }


    public Tuple(int item1, int item2)
    {
        this.Item1 = item1;
        this.Item2 = item2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        Tuple other;
        if (obj is Tuple)
        {
            other = (Tuple)obj;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.Item1 == other.Item1 && this.Item2 == other.Item2
          || this.Item1 == other.Item2 && this.Item2 == other.Item1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + Item1.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + Item2.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Tuple left, Tuple right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Tuple left, Tuple right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

But when I run distinct on a List of Tuples, it does not use my definition of Equals. For example, on a vertices variable, like below:

```
List<Tuple> vertices
```

I do:

```
var distinctVertices = vertices.Distinct();
```

And it does check for distinct values, but it doesn't pass through my Equals definition, thus not working in the case I described above. Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you can have equal items that have different hash codes.  To fix that make sure you use the smaller value in your hash first then the larger one.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say for sure what's wrong. But the code you posted definitely isn't correct. Your `Tuple` struct should implement `IEquatable<Tuple>`, not `IEquatable<object>`. You should also override `System.Object.Equals()`, calling the `IEquatable<Tuple>.Equals()` method from that method. Your hash implementation is wrong as well (as noted in @juharr's comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you probably want to implement `IEquatable<Tuple>`, not `IEquatable<object>` - `Tuple : IEquatable<Tuple>`.

---

Secondly, equality on a mutable `struct` is a terrible idea; I strongly suggest you use:

```cs
public readonly struct Tuple : IEquatable<Tuple>
{
    public int Item1 { get; }
    public int Item2 { get; }
    public Tuple(int item1, int item2)
    {
        Item1 = item1;
        Item2 = item2;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Thirdly, your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` must agree. If the order doesn't matter to `Equals`, it shouldn't matter to `GetHashCode`. Consider just:

```cs
public override int GetHashCode() => Item1 ^ Item2;
```

or something else that is not order dependent.

---

Finally,
your `Equals` can probably be simplfied:

```cs
public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Tuple other && Equals(other);
public bool Equals(Tuple other)
    => (Item1 == other.Item1 && Item2 == other.Item2)
    || (Item1 == other.Item2 && Item2 == other.Item1);
```

Comment: Very insightful answer, you made me feel ashamed of having posted this unpolished code. The biggest problem with the code was indeed my naive implementation of the GetHashCode(), and that is why I am accepting your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this note in the `Distinct` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8):

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

This means that, until you enumerate the result, nothing will happen in terms of filtering the sequence.

If you do a `foreach` or adding a `ToList` on the result, i.e:

```
var distinctVertices = vertices.Distinct().ToList();
```

or

```
foreach(var vertice in distinctVertices)
{
    // optionally do something here
}
```

Then you'll see your `Equals` method execute.

Comment: Indeed I see that execution of Distinct is being deferred. But I am surprised to see that the list does get filtered immediately after the Distinct() method, but before any enumeration takes place and without calling Equals(). How?

Comment: I was about to accept your answer, because taking the title in consideration, your answer is the one who actually answers it. But because the biggest issue with this code was the GetHashCode(), I decided to choose another option and change the title a little bit

Comment: You said, *"I am surprised to see that the list does get filtered immediately after the Distinct() method"*. Where do you see this? `Distinct<TSource>()` returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>`. There is no way to see filtering without enumerating the sequence (i.e. using `.Count()` or some other means). Is that what you're doing?

Comment: on the following code: https://pastebin.com/RVmx729L ; while debugging it, I receive a list with 12 vertices on that method, and right after the Distinct() call, I inspect the variable "distinctVertices" and the list has gotten filtered. However, no Equals method that I defined gets hit. That was why I posted this question, it just didn't make any sense to me!